# filter post by date selected in a dropdown in realtime

Tags: custom-post-types, dropdown

How to filter custom post type by selected month and year in a dropdown, do i have to make rewrite rules? or javascipt function?

```
$data_args = array(
    'post_type'=>'news-list',
    'order'=>'desc',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$dataQuery = new WP_Query( $data_args );

$accContent = [];

if($dataQuery -> have_posts()):
    while($dataQuery -> have_posts()): $dataQuery->the_post();
        $newArr = true;
        $id = get_the_id();
        $month = get_the_date('F');
        $year = get_the_date('Y');
        $monthnum = get_the_date('m');

        if(array_key_exists($year,$accContent)){
            if(array_key_exists($month,$accContent[$year]))
            {
                array_push($accContent[$year][$month],$id);
                $newArr = false;
            }
        }

        if($newArr){
            $accContent[$year][$month] = array($id);
        }

    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Are you just filtering a custom query, or the main post type archive? Is there a single dropdown for month & year or two separate dropdowns? Are you doing this with AJAX or on a form submission with query strings (?year=2018 etc.)?

Comment: @JacobPeattie, i am filtering post type archive, and i need a 2 separate dropdown for month and year, i want to filter posts upon selecting the month and year